# XAdES BES timestamp verification error

Tags: bouncycastle, xades4j

I am trying to use xades4j library for verification which uses bouncycastle for Xades-BES and I am getting the following stacktrace:

```
xades4j.verification.TimeStampInvalidSignatureException: Verification failed for property     'SignatureTimeStamp': invalid token signature
    at xades4j.verification.TimeStampVerifierBase.getEx(TimeStampVerifierBase.java:114)
    at xades4j.verification.TimeStampVerifierBase.verify(TimeStampVerifierBase.java:89)
    at xades4j.verification.TimeStampVerifierBase.verify(TimeStampVerifierBase.java:38)
    at xades4j.verification.QualifyingPropertiesVerifierImpl.verifyProperties(QualifyingPropertiesVerifierImpl.java:59)
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.getValidationDate(XadesVerifierImpl.java:250)
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:174)
    at com.signapplet.sign.SignComponent.verify(SignComponent.java:663)


Caused by: xades4j.providers.TimeStampTokenSignatureException: Invalid token signature or certificate
    at xades4j.providers.impl.DefaultTimeStampVerificationProvider.verifyToken(DefaultTimeStampVerificationProvider.java:154)
    at xades4j.verification.TimeStampVerifierBase.verify(TimeStampVerifierBase.java:71)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.tsp.TSPValidationException: certificate hash does not match certID hash.
    at org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampToken.validate(Unknown Source)
    at xades4j.providers.impl.DefaultTimeStampVerificationProvider.verifyToken(DefaultTimeStampVerificationProvider.java:150)
    ... 43 more
```

Here is the code from xades4j which throws exception:

```
try
{
    tsToken.validate(this.signerInfoVerifierBuilder.build(tsaCert)); //tsToken==org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampToken
}
catch (TSPValidationException ex)
{
    throw new TimeStampTokenSignatureException("Invalid token signature or certificate", ex);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new TimeStampTokenVerificationException("Error when verifying the token signature", ex);
}
```

The problem occurs only when I sign a file with a software provided by cryptoki tokens' manufacturer which by the way worked great till now and I was able to validate the same files with different validation software for xades. The problem occurs only in xades4j.

When I sign the same file with xades4j, it verifies everything as expected.

Below is the code for verification. certDataList is a list with all certificates from the document in String and getCert will return List. DummyCertificateValidationProvider returns ValidationData with a list of previously constructed x509certs.

```
    public boolean verify(final File file) {
        if (!Dictionaries.valid()) {
            return true;
        }
        certList = null;
        try {

            final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            final DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            final Document doc = db.parse(file);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            final NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ds:Signature");
            Element elem = null;
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                final Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    elem = (Element) nNode;
                }
            }
            final NodeList nList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("ds:X509Certificate");
            final List<String> certDataList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList2.getLength(); temp++) {
                final Node nNode = nList2.item(temp);
                certDataList.add(nNode.getTextContent());
            }
            certList = getCert(certDataList);

            final CertificateValidationProvider certValidator = new DummyCertificateValidationProvider(certList);

            final XadesVerificationProfile p = new XadesVerificationProfile(certValidator);
            final XadesVerifier v = p.newVerifier();
            final SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions opts = new SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions();

            // for relative document paths
            final String baseUri = "file:///" + file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/") + "/";
            LOGGER.debug("baseUri:" + baseUri);
            opts.useBaseUri(baseUri);
            v.verify(elem, opts);
            return true;
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException | XAdES4jException | CertificateException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
            LOGGER.error("XML not validated!", e);
        }

        return false;
}
```

Comment: How are you configuring certificate validation? Have you confirmed that the CertificateValidationProvider is returning the correct certificate (i.e the TSA certificate)? If this is correct, maybe there's some bug when obtaining the certificates from the TS token.

Comment: I added verification code with simple explanation. Nothing too fancy. CertificateValidationProvider always returns certificates which are constructed in verify method. This works great for document previously signed with xades4j. List of certs is correct. The main difference I see between file signed with xades4j and the other tool is that the other tool added <xades:EncapsulatedTimeStamp></xades:EncapsulatedTimeStamp>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CertificateValidationProvider` must return a `ValidationData` with the certificate chain that validates the certificate represented by the supplied `CertSelector`. As [described on the documentation](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/providers/ValidationData.html), the certificates on `ValidationData` should be in order, namely, the first certificate should be the signing certificate.

When validating a TS token, the signing certificate is the TSA's certificate. When `CertificateValidationProvider` is asked to do the validation with a CertSelector, it must return the TSA cert in the first position of the chain. The TS validation code will assume that it is in the first position, as documented.

In your validation code you're picking all the certificates in the signature. That list is not a valid certificate chain for ALL the needed certificate validations. Eventually,  the TSA certificate won't even be present on the signature.

I think you'll need to change your `CertificateValidationProvider` implementation to return, at least, the appropriate certificate in the first position. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I got into the XADES specification and it seems that I used XADES-T from manufacturer's tools. As I want to validate everything offline, I need only XADES-BES.